# Scheduled Posts - Plugin Missed Schedule - WP to Twitter

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-tasks

The feature to schedule posts in Wordpress 3.4.2 seems to be broken.
So I installed the plugin **WP Missed Schedule** that checks every 5 minutes for posts that match this problem.
I also use the Plugin **WP to Twitter** that supports the feature to tweet a new post automatically to Twitter - no matter whether the post is planned or not.

**Here is the problem:**

If there is a scheduled Post it will be published in Wordpress, supported by the Plugin WP Missed Schedule, but not tweeted!

The Code in WP Missed Schedule says:

```
wp_publish_post($scheduledID)
```

And the called Hook in WP to Twitter says:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', ...)
```

So is the Hook **publish_post** the right one for the function **wp_publish_post**?
I did not find any documentation about that.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a website using Tweetable. I added this line right after
wp_publish_post($scheduledID)

tweetable_publish_tweet($scheduledID);

But that wasn't the problem. There were a few lines in Tweetable that caused the posting function to exit if the modified date was after the publish date. When the plugin publishes the post it changes the modified date. I commented out the lines in Tweetable and it worked.

Comment: I added a "real" cron that runs every 5 Minute and it seems to work.